# Parse data from json local file using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

Is it possible to parse data from a local json file ,using AFNetworking instead of SBJSON?

Comment: yes just use a local file URL

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to do that?

Comment: @Cyrille im developing a code where the web service is not done, so for developments sake im simulating the json file received from the network in a local json file but i want to implement the correct code with AFNetworking now.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to use AFNetworking for local JSON. You won't have any network related advantage in local files.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName ofType:@"json"];
NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSONData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Now use  `jsonDictionary` as per your need.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just parse it using the built in `NSJSONSerialization` classes? That's all AFNetworking is doing behind the scenes. Save yourself some trouble.

Comment: Thanks.Let me try that out!

Answer (score 3):

```
NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:templateFileName ofType:@"json"]];
NSDictionary *parsedData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To load the local JSON file in iOS we need to go to build phases, by selecting the target, load the file using copy bundle resources. Then build the file.
Simply adding it by following 'file-> new file -> other -> empty' procedure wont work.(I was struggling for 4 hours for getting the expected result.)